# Deny access to .svn folders on Apache

Tags: svn, apache, deployment, capistrano

We have a rails application in subversion that we deploy with Capistrano but have noticed that we can access the files in '/.svn', which presents a security concern.

I wanted to know what the best way to do this.  A few ideas:

- Global Apache configuration to deny access
- Adding .htaccess files in the public folder and all subfolders
- Cap task that changes the permissions

I don't really like the idea of deleting the folders or using svn export, since I would like to keep the 'svn info' around.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to put .htaccess files in subfolders, the rules automatically apply to all subdirectories.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The best option is to use Apache configuration.

Using htaccess or global configuration depends mainly on if you control your server.

If you do, you can use something like

```
<DirectoryMatch .*\.svn/.*>
    Deny From All
</DirectoryMatch>
```

If you don't, you can do something similar in .htaccess files with FilesMatch

Comment: I could not get this to work with .htaccess and FilesMatch.
I could get it to block a request to http://site.com/.svn, but I could still access files if I directly requested them.

For now I am using the RedirectMatch as suggested below. The other option is a RewriteRule.

Comment: I used this approach combined with Riccardo Galli's list of multiple cvs systems to great effect:

`<DirectoryMatch .*\.(svn|git|hg|bzr|cvs)/.*>
    Deny From All
</DirectoryMatch>`

This matches all subdirectories / files also. It reveals only if the top level directory exists (otherwise it would return a 404) but .svn/doesnotexist returns a 403.

Comment: Not all servers are configured to overwrite this httpd.conf settings from .htaccess. If works; you are lucky.

Comment: For Apache 2.4+: `<DirectoryMatch "/\.svn"> Require all denied </DirectoryMatch>`

Answer (score 44):

One other way to protect the .svn files would be to use a redirect in the Apache config:

```
RedirectMatch 404 /\\.svn(/|$)
```

So instead of getting a 403 forbidden (and providing clues to would be attackers) you get a 404, which is what we would expect when randomly typing in paths.

Comment: Yes, this is non HTTP-compliant though :)

Comment: Why is this _not_ HTTP-compliant? By the way, it worked great for me, thanks!

Answer (score 30):

I do not like the idea of 404ing each file startig wit a dot.
I'd use a more selective approach, either with the cvs I'm using in the project (svn in the example)

```
RedirectMatch 404 /\\.svn(/|$)
```

or a catch all cvs systems

```
RedirectMatch 404 /\\.(svn|git|hg|bzr|cvs)(/|$)
```

-- outdated answer follows (see comments) --

I cant write comments yet so...
The answer of csexton is incorrect, because an user cannot access the .svn folder, but can access any files inside it !
e.g. you can access
http://myserver.com/.svn/entries

The correct rule is

```
RedirectMatch 404 /\\.svn(/.*|$)
```

Comment: The .* is not necessary, the answer of csexton is sufficient. csexton's regex matches "/.svn" at the end of the requested path or "/.svn/" anywhere in the requested path. So it will also work for requests to /path/to/.svn/entries.

Comment: Did you try? I did and I had access to .svn/entries with csexton rule

Comment: I'm using the rule `RedirectMatch 404 /\.svn(/|$)` on Apache 2.2 and get a 404 with /.svn/entries

Comment: You're right. I wrote this answer because the behaviour was different at that time. It seems like today Apache use the regexp as partial if $ is missing (which makes sense). I'll update my answer. Thank you

Comment: I suspected something like that, that's why I mentioned my Apache version number. The current behaviour makes more sense, that's right.

Answer (score 14):

I think Riccardo Galli got it right.  Even apache already had .svn setup as forbidden for me, but .svn/entries was certainly available...exposing my svn server, port number, usernames, etc.

I actually figure, why not restrict .git as a preventative measure (say you don't use git yet but may someday at which time you will not be thinking about directory restrictions).

And then I thought, why not restrict everything that should be hidden anyway?  Can anyone conceive of a problem with this?

```
RedirectMatch 404 /\\..*(/.*|$)
```

I added the '.*' after the initial period - only difference from Riccardo.  Seems to 404 .svn, .git, .blah, etc.

Comment: This works well with .hg (Mercurial). It protects also the nested folders and files.

Comment: Because you only have to check if a URL path contains a forward-slash followed by a dot, this should also work:
  `RedirectMatch 404 /\.`

Comment: The cleanest formally-correct regex would be: `RedirectMatch 404 /\..*$`

Answer (score 6):

I would rather deny access to all dot-files (eg: .htaccess, .svn, .xxx, etc.), as they normally don't need to be web-accessible.

Here's the rule to achieve this (until Apache 2.2 included):

```
<LocationMatch "\/\..*">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</LocationMatch>
```

*(UPDATE)* Or you can use the following (which works in Apache 2.2 and 2.4):

```
# Deny access to dot-files, as 404 error
# (not giving hint about potential existence to the file)
RedirectMatch 404 ".*\/\..*"
```

Comment: @w00t just changed to propose a working solution on 2.4, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

RedirectMatch like other directives from mod_alias is case sensitive even on case-insensitive file systems (see [mod_alias documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html)). So the answers above about matching and blocking files of all version control systems are not correct.

Instead of

```
RedirectMatch 404 /\\.(svn|git|hg|bzr|cvs)(/|$)
```

or

```
RedirectMatch permanent .*\.(svn|git|hg|bzr|cvs)/.* /
```

something like this is necessary

```
RedirectMatch 404 "(?i)/\.?(cvs|svn|git|hg|bzr)"
```

to really block everything, because

- CVS directories are uppercase; and
- don't start with a dot (.) in front.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

A RedirectMatch will respond with a 404, which is great.

However, if "Options +Indexes" is enabled, then users will still be able to see the '.svn' directory from the Parent directory.

Users won't be able to enter the directory-- this is where the '404 Not Found' comes in. However, they will be able to see the directory and provide clues to would be attackers.

Answer (score 1):

I seems to me, Apache conf should be :

```
<Directory ~ "\.svn">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not all that fond of RedirectMatch, so I used a RewriteRule instead:

```
RewriteRule /\..*(/.*|$) - [R=404,L]
```

The hyphen means "don't do any substitution". I also could not figure out why, in the examples above, the regex had two backslashes:

```
/\\..*(/.*|$)
```

So I took one out and it works fine.  I can't figure out why you would use two there. Someone care to enlighten me?

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've found it can be even simpler, too: `RewriteRule /\. - [R=403,L]` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
RedirectMatch permanent .*\.(svn|git|hg|bzr|cvs)/.* /
```

can also be used if you don't want to send an error back to the user.

It's only redirecting back to the site rootpage. Also, this is a permanent redirect, so the robots won't try to reindex this URL.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Subversion FAQ is sugesting this solution:

```
# Disallow browsing of Subversion working copy administrative dirs.
<DirectoryMatch "^/.*/\.svn/">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</DirectoryMatch>
```

source: https://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#website-auto-update

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess on your server config file.

(1)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^(.*/)?\.git/" - [F,L]
```

And 
(2)

```
RedirectMatch 404 /\.git
```

Place this both method in `.htaccess` file.

It hides any file or directory whose name begins with .git Like  .git directory or .gitignore file by returning a 404.

Answer (score -7):

Create a access rights file in your subversion server installation.

e.g if you folder structure is

*/svn*

*/svn/rights/svnauth.conf*

create a configuration file and enter the path of that file in your apache subversion configuration file which you would normally find at */etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf*

In your svnauth.conf file define the rights as :

## access rights for Foo.com

[foo.com:/trunk/source]

dev1=rw

dev2=rw
.....

This way you can control the access rights from one single file and at much granular level.

For more information peruse through the svn red book.

Comment: You have misunderstood the question. He is talking about the .svn directory that gets created on checkout, not about developers permissions on the repository