# Using hg repository as web site

Tags: web, mercurial, tortoisehg

This is somewhat related to my security question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361626/security-deny-access-to-hg-via-mod-rewrite). Is it a bad idea to use an hg / mercurial repository for a live website? If so, why?

Furthermore, we have dev, test and production installations of our website, like `dev.example.com`, `test.example.com` and `www.example.com`. If it's a bad idea to use a repository for a live/production website, would it be OK to use an hg repository for the dev and test sites?

I'm also concerned about ease of deployment. We have technical and less technical co-workers who will be working with the site. The technical people (software engineers) won't have any problem working with the command line or TortoiseHG. I'm more concerned about the less technical people (web designers). They won't be comfortable working on the command line, and may even find TortoiseHG daunting. These co-workers mostly upload `.css` files and images to the server. I'd like for these files (at least the `.css` files) to be under version control, but I want this to be as transparent as possible for the non technical team members.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Edit:
Our 'site' is actually a multi-site CMS setup with a main repository and several subrepositories. Mock-up of the repository structure:

```
/root [main repository containing core files and subrepositories]
    /modules [modules subrepository]
    /sites/global [subrepository for global .css and .php files]
    /sites/site1 [site1 subrepository]
    ...
    /sites/siteN [siteN subrepository]
```

Software engineers would work in the `root`, `modules` and `sites/global` repositories. Less technical people (web designers) would work only in the `site1` ... `siteN` subrepositories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is a bad idea.

Do not have your repository as your website. It means that things checked in, but unworking, will immediately be available. And it means that accidental checkins (it happens) will be reflected live as well (i.e. documents that don't belong there, etc).

I actually address this "concept" however (source control as deployment) with a tool I've written (a few other companies are addressing this topic now, as well, so you'll see it more). Mine is for SVN (at the moment) so it's not particularly relevant; I mention it only to show that I've considered this previously (not on a Repository though; a working copy, in that scenario the answer is the same: better to have a non-versioned "free" are as the website directory, and automate (via user action) the copying of the 'versioned' data to that directory).

Comment: I had planned to allow most users to `push` to the `dev` site, but only allow a few admins to push to the `test` and `live` sites. Does this change your answer at all?

Comment: @Tex: No, not really. Consider this: You're effectively making your source control more "risky" to use. People need to think 'okay, not only is this ready for commit, but is it ready for dev deployment? It's relevant in places where more than one 'dev' may be testing, and other similar scenarios. I'd stick with the thought that you want your source control to be 'easy' to use, and that deployment is a 'separate' action (maybe I'm biased here, because it's something that I specifically work on). My views, FWIW.

Comment: Thanks for talking this through with me. I'd considered some of these points. I've also considered setting up a sandbox/developer-testing site for each developer on our web server (again, with each site being an hg repository). Then I could allow each developer/designer to `push` to his sandbox site for testing and only allow admins to push to `dev`, `test` and `live`. I'm having a difficult time coming up with a workflow that non technical guys can easily follow.

Comment: @Tex: No problem. Indeed, with my system I'm working on a similar approach (you deploy changes through a progression: commit, build, deploy (to where you wish, typically "test"), then test is upgraded to staging, and staging is upgraded to live. Other intricacies on the way. I don't use HG, so I don't quite know if a 'push' is different from a 'commit' (I think it might be, but I'm not sure). All I'd want to be sure of is: 1) `commit` is easy, and doesn't need to "work", 2) deployment is (typically) done separately and "manually" (configurable to automatic or manual). 3) Accidental deployments

Comment: ... can easily be reversed. Assuming your system is setup like so, then it sounds "reasonable" to me. But I'm not sure how easy/possible it is to do that in HG. And certainly, with SVN, you wouldn't want to point a website at the *repository*, because there are lots of strange files in there. With HG it may not be the case.

Answer (score 4):

Many folks keep their sites in repositories, and so long as you **don't have people live-editing the live-site** you're fine.  Have a staging/dev area where your non-revision control folks make their changes and then have someone more RCS-friendly do the commit-pull-merge-push cycle periodically.

So long as it's the conscious action of a judging human doing the staging-area -> production-repo push you're fine. You can even put a hook into the production clone that automatically does a 'hg update' of the working directory within that production clone, so that 'push' is all it takes to deploy.

That said, I think you're underestimating either your web team or tortoiseHg; they can get this.

Answer (score 2):

me personally (i'm a team of 1) and i quite like the idea of using src control as a live website. more so with hg, then with svn.

the way i see it, you can load an entire site, (add/remove files) with a single cmd
much easier then ftp/ssh this, delete that etc

if you are using apache (and probably iis as well) you can make a simple .htaccess file that will block all .hg files (or .svn if you are using svn)

my preferred structure is 
development site is on local machine running directly out of a repository (no security is really required here, do what you like commit as required)

staging/test machine is a separate box or vm running a recent copy of the live database
(i have a script to push committed changes to staging server and run tests)

live machine
(open ssh connection, push changes to live server, test again, can all be scripted reasonably easily, google for examples)

because of push/pull nature of hg, it means you can commit changes and test without the danger of pushing a broken build to the live website. like you say in your comments, only specific people should have permission to push a version to the live site.  (if it fails, you should easily be able to revert to the previous version, via src control)

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a repo also be an active web server (for dev or test/QA environment anyway)?

Here's what I am trying to implement:

- Developers have local test environments in which they can build and test their code
- Developers make a clone of the dev environment on their local dev machine
- Developers commit as often as they want to their local repo
- When chunk of work is done and tested, then developer pushes working change sets to dev repo

Changes would be merged and tested on Dev, then pushed to Test/QA, and so on.

BTW, we're using Mercurial.  I believe this model would only work using a distributed source code management tool.