# SVN publish to Apache after commit and merge

Tags: apache, svn

I'm pretty new to SVN so this might be a simple one, but I guarantee it took me the whole day already. This is the setup:

Apache installed under /www/ and the website is under /www/htdocs/example.com/www/

I have a working SVN server (same machine) and I'd like to publish, either manually or automatically after commit (using hooks), the contents to the destination: /www/htdocs/example.com/www/. The repo is under /svn/www.example.com. I have encountered two problems so far:

1. If I run "**svn export --force file:///svn/www.example.com /www/htdocs/example.com/www**" than it creates a new dir: /www/htdocs/example.com/www/www.example.com. Can I do an export without the root directory, but only its contents?
2. The website root dir (/www/htdocs/example.com/www) is already having files uploaded by the users, so exporting from svn should overwrite only the files found in the repo and leave the rest intact (basically a merge).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of an export, you can create a checkout to your www directory instead. You can [deny access to .svn folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/398008/33499) in apache.

Then when there is a commit on the SVN server, update your working copy and set it to discard local conflicting changes:

```
svn update --accept theirs-full /www/htdocs/example.com/www
```

You can also execute `svn revert` first to discard all local changes. `svn checkout --force`[should also work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312519/33499).

Comment: If I do a `svn co file:///svn/www.example.com /www/htdocs/example.com/www` I end up with the following dir: /www/htdocs/example.com/www/www.example.com/
I need to have the files in the repo directly under /www/htdocs/example.com/www

Comment: Found it! The problem was how the Eclipse project was configured to use SVN. The www.example.com folder was created in the SVN by Eclipse (actually that was me, and my stupid configuration). Thanks!