# Why double slash dot (ie: \\.) in htaccess regex?

Tags: regex, apache, pcre, mod-alias

From another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398008/deny-access-to-svn-folders-on-apache), this double slash dot is common

```
RedirectMatch 404 /\\.svn(/|$)
```

Since we're matching "/.svn" etc., why isn't this a single slash to escape the period?

Comment: According to [this help page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) the backslash must be single to match a literal dot.

Comment: If there is anyone who could explain the [source code](http://opensource.apple.com/source/apache/apache-647/apache/src/modules/standard/mod_alias.c),  I will upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double escaping is allowed here but not really required. So both of these rules will work:

```
RedirectMatch 410 /\\.svn(/|$)
```

OR

```
RedirectMatch 410 /\.svn(/|$)
```

Comment: Why does that work though? If you wanted to literally match a file called `\.svn` the double backslash doesn't work, but you need to use the regex `/\\\.svn` (3 of them), whereas the PCRE backslash works differently in mod_rewrite (only need 1, but 2 will match the file \.svn).

Comment: Good point Jon. I just went by this line in question `Since we're matching "/.svn" etc`. I am not sure if `RedirectMatch` (or `mod_alias`) regex engine is same as as the one used by `mod_rewrite` (PCRE).

Comment: @JonLin I can understand the `/\\\.svn` matching `\.svn` literally. I do have  problem understanding why `\\.svn` works though

Comment: In this example, we're excluding access to ".svn" folders, so my assumption is the pattern is "/.svn", not "/\.svn". If I understand correctly, the conclusion so far is that both "\\." and "\." stand for a single period, but nobody knows why?

Comment: @Eric: Yes that is correct both `\\.` and `\.` behave same for `RedirectMatch` directive.